# How to compare two employee tables column by column in oracle for each employee

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot

I have to compare the data in two Oracle employee table column-wise and create a report like this (Ato B compare)

Table A

```
+-------+------+---------+
|emp_num| name | a_city  |
+-------+------+---------+  
|  1    | Jo   | Lay     |
|  2    | Paul | Dubai   |
+-------+------+---------+
```

Table B

```
+-------+------+---------+
|emp_num| name | a_city  |
+-------+------+---------+  
|  1    | Jo   | Sydney  |
+-------+------+---------+
```

After Comparing data in A and B output is  like below

```
+----------+----------+-----------+---------------+----------+---------+------------+-------+-------+-------------+
| status   | a_emp_num| b_emp_num | emp_num_match | a_city   | b_city  | city_match | a_name| b_name|  name_match |
+----------+----------+-----------+---------------+----------+---------+------------+-------+-------+-------------+  
| Found    |  1       |  1        |   Matched     |  Lay     |   Lay   | Matched    |  Jo   |   Jo  |  Matched    |
| Not Found|  2       |           |   Not Matched |  Dubai   |         | Not Matched|  Paul |       |  Not Matched|
+----------+----------+-----------+---------------+----------+---------+------------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

I have a query created to compare this

```
SELECT (CASE
         WHEN A.EMP_NUM IS NULL THEN
          'Found'
         ELSE
          'Not Found'
       END) AS STATUS,
       
       A.EMP_NUM A_EMP_NUM,
       B.EMP_NUM B_EMP_NUM,
       
       (CASE
         WHEN NVL(TRIM(B.EMP_NUM), 0) = NVL(TRIM(B.EMP_NUM), 0) THEN
          'Found'
         ELSE
          'Not Found'
       END) AS EMP_NUM_MATCH
  FROM A, B
 WHERE A.EMP_NUM = B.EMP_NUM(+)
```

now  the issue is that I have to write the  case statement for many attributes like NAME,AGE ,CITY(in real case 400+ attributes )

Is there any way to create this select statement automatically if we pass the list of columns as input? or any way to do this comparison for all the columns in excel without explicitly writing select for each of the columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a query which will write a query for you. Something like this:

```
DECLARE
   l_str  VARCHAR2 (4000) := 'select ';
BEGIN
   FOR cr IN (  SELECT a.column_name cn
                  FROM user_tab_columns a
                 WHERE a.table_name = 'TABLE_A'
              ORDER BY column_id)
   LOOP
      l_str :=
            l_str
         || 'a.'
         || cr.cn
         || ', b.'
         || cr.cn
         || ', '
         || 'case when nvl(trim(a.'
         || cr.cn
         || '), 0) = nvl  ( trim    ( b . '
         || cr.cn
         || '), 0) then ''match'' else ''mismatch'' end '
         || cr.cn
         || ',';
   END LOOP;

   l_str :=
         RTRIM (l_str, ',')
      || ' from table_a a left join table_b b on a . empno = b . empno ';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_str);
END;
/
```

The result is a `SELECT` statement; I formatted it so that it is easier to read:

```
SELECT a.EMPNO,
       b.EMPNO,
       CASE
          WHEN NVL (TRIM (a.EMPNO), 0) = NVL (TRIM (b.EMPNO), 0) THEN 'match'
          ELSE 'mismatch'
       END EMPNO,
       a.NAME,
       b.NAME,
       CASE
          WHEN NVL (TRIM (a.NAME), 0) = NVL (TRIM (b.NAME), 0) THEN 'match'
          ELSE 'mismatch'
       END NAME,
       a.CITY,
       b.CITY,
       CASE
          WHEN NVL (TRIM (a.CITY), 0) = NVL (TRIM (b.CITY), 0) THEN 'match'
          ELSE 'mismatch'
       END CITY
  FROM table_a a LEFT JOIN table_b b ON a.empno = b.empno
```

which - when executed - returns

```
     EMPNO      EMPNO EMPNO    NAME NA NAME     CITY  CITY   CITY
---------- ---------- -------- ---- -- -------- ----- ------ --------
         1          1 match    Jo   Jo match    Lay   Sydney mismatch
         2            mismatch Paul    mismatch Dubai        mismatch
```

Now that you know "how", make it prettier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
select CASE WHEN B.EMP_NUM is NOT null THEN 'Found' ELSE 'Not Found' END AS STATUS,
       A.EMP_NUM A_EMP_NUM,
       B.EMP_NUM B_EMP_NUM,
       CASE WHEN B.EMP_NUM is NOT null THEN 'Match' ELSE 'Mismatch' END AS EMP_NUM_MATCH,
       A.CITY AS A_CITY,
       B.CITY AS B_CITY,
       CASE WHEN A.CITY = B.CITY THEN 'Match' ELSE 'Mismatch' END AS CITY_MATCH,
       A.NAME AS A_NAME,
       B.NAME AS B_NAME,
       CASE WHEN A.NAME = B.NAME THEN 'Match' ELSE 'Mismatch' END AS NAME_MATCH
  from A LEFT JOIN B ON A.EMP_NUM =B.EMP_NUM
```

Comment: Hi My select statement is  working fine...but the issue is that I have 300 plus columns and the columns will change and it is very difficult for me to write a case statement for each column, is there any way to  generate the select query for all the columns in a table or do case statetment for all the columns in table

Comment: You can use USER_TAB_COLS and create the query SELECT clause expressions - `CASE WHEN B.EMP_NUM is NOT null THEN 'Found' ELSE 'Not Found' END AS STATUS,
       A.EMP_NUM A_EMP_NUM,
       B.EMP_NUM B_EMP_NUM` for each column

Comment: how to include USER_TAB_COLS in sql sorry I am not sure about that

Comment: You can not add `USER_TAB_COLS` in this query but you can use the following query to create your original query - `SELECT 'CASE WHEN B.' || COLUMN_NAME ||' is NOT null THEN ''Match'' ELSE ''Mismatch'' END AS ' || COLUMN_NAME ||'_MATCH,
       A.' || COLUMN_NAME ||' AS ' || COLUMN_NAME ||',
       B.' || COLUMN_NAME ||' AS ' || COLUMN_NAME ||','
FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_A_TABLE_NAME'
ORDER BY COLUMN_ID;` You should copy paste each row and use it in your query

Answer (score 0):

Full Join and decode function work fine together for all cases of mismatch in both tables as decode decode managed well the nulls values.

```sql
select 
  decode(a.empno, b.empno, 'Found', 'NotFound') status
, a.empno "A.EMPNO", b.empno "B.EMPNO"
, decode(a.empno, b.empno, 'Match', 'Mismatch') "EMP_NUM.MATCH"
, a.city "a.CITY", b.city "B.CITY"
, decode(a.city, b.city, 'Match', 'Mismatch') "CITY.MATCH"
, a.name "A.NAME", b.name "B.NAME"
, decode(a.name, b.name, 'Match', 'Mismatch')"NAME.MATCH"
from tableA a
full join tableB b on (a.empno = b.empno)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option in order to pivot your data dynamically would be creating a function through use of `XMLELEMENT()`, `XMLAGG()` and `NVL2()` functions together to construct the `SELECT` statement such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_city_people_info RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_str       VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  SELECT RTRIM(DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(
                 XMLAGG( 
                         XMLELEMENT(e,'A.'||column_name||' AS  "a_'||column_name||'",
                                       B.'||column_name||' AS  "b_'||column_name||'", 
                                       DECODE( NVL2(A.'||column_name||',TRIM(A.'||column_name||'),'' ''),
                                               NVL2(B.'||column_name||',TRIM(B.'||column_name||'),'' ''),
                                               ''Matched'',''Not Matched'' ) AS "'||column_name||'_match",')
                        ).EXTRACT('//text()').GETCLOBVAL() ,1),',')
    INTO v_str                    
    FROM 
    (
     SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(c.column_name) AS column_name
       FROM user_tab_cols c
      WHERE c.table_name = 'A' -- considering both tables(A and B) have exactly common columns 
    ); 

  v_sql :=
  'SELECT NVL2(B.emp_num , ''Found'', ''Not Found'') AS "status",'|| v_str ||'
     FROM A
     LEFT JOIN B
       ON B.emp_num = A.emp_num';

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

which will yield `SYS_REFCURSOR` return type, then call

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := get_city_people_info;
PRINT rc
```

from SQL Developer's command line.

<kbd>[Demo with generated SELECT Statement Within The Function](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=84110ef985ce5eba1cac0a06f1acce72)</kbd>

*P.S: Prefer using **JOIN** clauses for your queries rather than old-style having comma-seperated table type queries.*